# How to get IOptions in ConfigureServices method or pass IOptions into extension method?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm developing asp .net core web api 2.1 app.

I add JWT authentication service as an extension method in static class:

```
public static class AuthenticationMiddleware
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddJwtAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, string issuer, string key)
    {
        services
            .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // validate the server that created that token
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    // ensure that the recipient of the token is authorized to receive it
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    // check that the token is not expired and that the signing key of the issuer is valid
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    // verify that the key used to sign the incoming token is part of a list of trusted keys
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = issuer,
                    ValidAudience = issuer,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
                };
            });

        return services;
    }
}
```

which I use in ConfigureServices method of Startup class like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // adding some services omitted here

    services.AddJwtAuthentication(Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], Configuration["Jwt:Key"]);

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

Now, I have a requirement to use IOptions pattern to get JWT authentication data from appsettings.json

How can I get IOptions in ConfigureServices method to pass issuer and key into extension method? Or how to pass IOptions to extension method?

Comment: why do you need IOptions here?

Comment: Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#accessing-options-during-startup) say "Don't use IOptions<TOptions> or IOptionsMonitor<TOptions> in Startup.ConfigureServices. An inconsistent options state may exist due to the ordering of service registrations.".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For binding data from `appsettings.json` to `Model`, you could follow steps below:

1. Appsettings.json content

   ```
   {
   "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
       "Default": "Warning"
          }
    },      
    "JWT": {
         "Issuer": "I",
         "Key": "K"
       }
    }
   ```
2. JWT Options

   ```
   public class JwtOptions
   {
       public string Issuer { get; set; }
       public string Key { get; set; }
    }
   ```
3. Startup.cs

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.Configure<JwtOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("JWT"));
       var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
       var opt = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<JwtOptions>>().Value;
       services.AddJwtAuthentication(opt.Issuer, opt.Key);
       services.AddMvc();
   }
   ```
4. One more option to pass `JwtOptions` directly.

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.Configure<JwtOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("JWT"));
       var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
       var opt = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<JwtOptions>>().Value;
       services.AddJwtAuthentication(opt);

       services.AddMvc();
   }
   ```
5. Change the extension method.

   ```
   public static IServiceCollection AddJwtAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, JwtOptions opt)
   ```

Comment: Regarding options 3 & 4: It doesn't seem like a good idea to `BuildServiceProvider()` within `ConfigureServices`. Docs also say "Don't use IOptions<TOptions> or IOptionsMonitor<TOptions> in Startup.ConfigureServices. An inconsistent options state may exist due to the ordering of service registrations." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#accessing-options-during-startup

Answer (score 6):

One other option is to bind the configurations to a class with the `Bind()` extension. (IMO this a more clean solution then the IOptions)

```cs
public class JwtKeys
{
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var jwtKeys = new JwtKeys();
    Configuration.GetSection("JWT").Bind(JwtKeys);

    services.AddJwtAuthentication(jwtKeys);
}

public static IServiceCollection AddJwtAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, JwtKeys jwtKeys)
{....}
```

Then if you need the JwtKeys settings some other place in the solution, just register the class on the collection and inject it where needed

```cs
services.AddSingleton(jwtKeys);
```

Comment: `Configuration.GetSection("JWT")` gives me:
`error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Configuration.GetSection(string)'`

Comment: @IanGrainger make sure u have initialized the IConfiguration property Configuration

Comment: yeah, I haven't. I wanted to use IOptions, really, not specify the file and add Environment variables and all that gubbins.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your options to DI container in Startup class like this:

```
public class JwtOptions
{
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }

}

public void ConfigureService(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<JwtOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Jwt"));
}
```

Now you can use this options, in a configure stage, or in an extension method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<JwtOptions>();
    // write your own code
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not appear to answer the question. The OP wants to access `IOptions` inside of `ConfigureServices` rather than in `Configure`.

Comment: despite it isn't working for OP, it working for me. Thanks!